# Tournament pairing algorithm, groups of 4 as round robin, then swiss?

Tags: round-robin, tournament

I'm looking for a combination of Swiss and round robin paring. We have a (volleyball) tournament that spans 4 weeks. Some 64 teams are divided into 16 groups of 4 teams, the first round is based on geography. In each group, every team plays against all other teams. After the first round of 3 matches per team, I'd like to apply some Swiss paring to make new groups of teams of equal strength, geography is less important. Similarly, after the second and third round, new groups should be created using Swiss. After the fourth round a winner is announced per group.

Is there an algorithm for this, especially for the Swiss pairing part?

TIA

Comment: The only reason I can answer this is because I do this a lot in my applications. But if no code is included in the request, it's hard to provide any in the response. If you edit the question to include code examples of what you have tried and tag it with the language, then we can provide a more directly usable and software specific response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario of 4 rounds, with 16 groups of 4, we can precompute the matchups based on the results of each round according to the following algorithm.

- Here we define Swiss as no two teams being assigned to the same group in subsequent rounds, but for each round the teams are matched up according to skill/ability such that the top ranked teams only play other top ranked teams.

> ### Round 2:
>
> #### R2 Group 1
>
> - #1 from Group 1
> - #1 from Group 2
> - #1 from Group 3
> - #1 from Group 4
>
> #### R2 Group 2
>
> - #1 from Group 5
> - #1 from Group 6
> - #1 from Group 7
> - #1 from Group 8
>
> #### R2 Group 3
>
> - #1 from Group 9
> - #1 from Group 10
> - #1 from Group 11
> - #1 from Group 12
>
> #### R2 Group 4
>
> - #1 from Group 13
> - #1 from Group 14
> - #1 from Group 15
> - #1 from Group 16
>
> #### R2 Group 5
>
> - #2 from Group 1
> - #2 from Group 2
> - #2 from Group 3
> - #2 from Group 4
>
> ...
>
> #### R2 Group 16
>
> - #4 from Group 13
> - #4 from Group 14
> - #4 from Group 15
> - #4 from Group 16

This hardcoded schedule should be the same that you would get from applying the swiss procedure, but after round 2, the top teams have still not seen each other, so instead of dynamically allocating we can use the fixed outcomes from Round 1 and are guaranteed that the teams have not played each other:

> #### R3 Group 1
>
> - #1 from R2 Group 1 (Only played #1 R1G1-4)
> - #1 from R2 Group 2 (Only played #1 R1G5-8)
> - #1 from R2 Group 3 (Only played #1 R1G9-12)
> - #1 from R2 Group 4 (Only played #1 R1G13-16)
>
> #### R3 Group 2
>
> - #1 from R2 Group 5 (Only played #2 R1G1-4)
> - #1 from R2 Group 6 (Only played #2 R1G5-8)
> - #1 from R2 Group 7 (Only played #2 R1G9-12)
> - #1 from R2 Group 8 (Only played #2 R1G13-16)
>
> #### R3 Group 2
>
> - #1 from R2 Group 9 (Only played #3 R1G1-4)
> - #1 from R2 Group 10 (Only played #3 R1G5-8)
> - #1 from R2 Group 11 (Only played #3 R1G9-12)
> - #1 from R2 Group 12 (Only played #3 R1G13-16)
>
> ...
>
> #### R3 Group 16
>
> - #4 from R2 Group 13 (Only played #4 R1G1-4)
> - #4 from R2 Group 14 (Only played #4 R1G5-8)
> - #4 from R2 Group 15 (Only played #4 R1G9-12)
> - #4 from R2 Group 16 (Only played #4 R1G13-16)

We can again apply the same logic to the 4th Round, but round 4 is the last time that this can guarantee unique pairings:

> ### Round 4
>
> #### R4 Group 1
>
> - #1 from R3 Group 1 (Only played #1 R1, #1 R2G1-4)
> - #1 from R3 Group 2 (Only played #2 R1, #1 R2G5-8)
> - #1 from R3 Group 3 (Only played #3 R1, #1 R2G9-12)
> - #1 from R3 Group 4 (Only played #4 R1, #1 R2G13-16)
>
> #### R4 Group 2
>
> - #1 from R3 Group 5 (Only played #2 R1G1-4)
> - #1 from R3 Group 6 (Only played #2 R1G5-8)
> - #1 from R3 Group 7 (Only played #2 R1G9-12)
> - #1 from R3 Group 8 (Only played #2 R1G13-16)
>
> ...
>
> #### R4 Group 16
>
> - #4 from R3 Group 13 (Only played #4 R1G1-4)
> - #4 from R3 Group 14 (Only played #4 R1G5-8)
> - #4 from R3 Group 15 (Only played #4 R1G9-12)
> - #4 from R3 Group 16 (Only played #4 R1G13-16)

After 4 swiss rounds, if we were to apply this logic again then some teams **WILL** play each other again. Ideally if you want an overall winner you might choose to cull the list based on overall ranking and start again fresh (so ignore the previous matches for the purpose/rules of swissing) or use a round-robin approach from there.

If you wanted to continue swissing past the 4th round for this dataset and maintain that no team plays each other twice you can rank all the teams into a list. Then apply the swissing logic, but instead of checking against 1 opponent, check against the next 3.

Treat this as a sorting algorithm, following these steps:

1. Take the top 4
2. #1 team stays at the top
3. If #2 team has played #1, #3, #4 (any of the top 4), move them to the next group (placeholder for now)
4. Take the next team from the original list (#5)
   ...

Cycle through the teams until you have the first group.
Then take the teams from the placeholder group (maintaining the ranked order) with the remainder of the original list and begin the process again.

## UPDATE:

I've put together a fiddle that demonstrates 1 application of the above matrix vs a brute force or dynamically allocated Swiss style draw: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XF0gkl

In this proof, the Team number indicates their relative skill rank. To make the outcome predictable, the higher rank will always win. The teams are randomly distributed at the start, but you can see (in the final table at the end) for both the pre-computed matrix and the dynamic draw that the higher skilled teams come to the relative top over the 4 rounds.

- In both outcomes 15 of the top 16 skilled teams end up in the top 16 overall ranked teams.
- In the Matrix there are 6 of the top 8 skilled in the top 8 ranked
- In the Dynamic there are 7 of the top 8 skilled in the top 8 ranked
- The top 16 is adequate to now run a knockout or round robin tournament to find an overall winner.
- Top 8 in the matrix misses team #4, who would want to appeal if they missed out on the finals, #6 would probably also protest in the dynamic

Overall, even though the group stage does a good job (via either method) to identify the best teams, 4 rounds in groups of 4 is not conclusive enough to produce outright winners alone, but for only playing 12 teams out of the 64, it's not bad.

**Key:** Team (score) G[group]

| RANK | Round 4 Matrix | Round 4 Dynamic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #1 | 1 (34) G[ 3] | 1 (33) G[ 1] |
| #2 | 3 (33) G[ 2] | 10 (31) G[ 4] |
| #3 | 2 (33) G[ 1] | 2 (31) G[ 1] |
| #4 | 5 (32) G[ 5] | 3 (30) G[ 1] |
| #5 | 9 (31) G[ 7] | 7 (29) G[ 2] |
| #6 | 6 (31) G[ 1] | 4 (29) G[ 2] |
| #7 | 7 (31) G[ 6] | 5 (29) G[ 2] |
| #8 | 11 (31) G[10] | 8 (29) G[ 2] |
| #9 | 8 (31) G[ 1] | 16 (29) G[ 5] |
| #10 | 12 (30) G[ 4] | 9 (28) G[ 3] |
| #11 | 13 (30) G[13] | 12 (28) G[ 3] |
| #12 | 14 (30) G[ 9] | 6 (28) G[ 1] |
| #13 | 4 (30) G[ 5] | 13 (28) G[ 3] |
| #14 | 10 (30) G[ 2] | 24 (28) G[ 7] |
| #15 | 18 (29) G[11] | 11 (28) G[ 3] |
| #16 | 16 (29) G[ 6] | 14 (28) G[ 5] |
| #17 | 17 (28) G[ 9] | 19 (28) G[ 8] |
| #18 | 21 (28) G[14] | 15 (28) G[ 4] |
| #19 | 22 (28) G[ 3] | 17 (26) G[ 6] |
| #20 | 19 (28) G[ 8] | 21 (26) G[10] |
| #21 | 20 (27) G[13] | 18 (26) G[ 6] |
| #22 | 35 (27) G[ 4] | 20 (26) G[ 6] |
| #23 | 27 (26) G[14] | 29 (26) G[ 7] |
| #24 | 15 (26) G[ 2] | 32 (25) G[ 8] |
| #25 | 32 (25) G[12] | 27 (25) G[ 9] |
| #26 | 30 (25) G[10] | 31 (25) G[ 9] |
| #27 | 36 (25) G[ 8] | 28 (25) G[ 9] |
| #28 | 24 (25) G[15] | 26 (25) G[ 4] |
| #29 | 28 (25) G[ 3] | 23 (25) G[ 4] |
| #30 | 34 (24) G[ 7] | 30 (24) G[10] |
| #31 | 29 (24) G[ 9] | 22 (24) G[ 5] |
| #32 | 33 (24) G[ 6] | 33 (24) G[13] |
| #33 | 31 (24) G[ 7] | 40 (24) G[11] |
| #34 | 26 (24) G[ 5] | 25 (24) G[ 5] |
| #35 | 23 (24) G[ 1] | 38 (24) G[11] |
| #36 | 40 (23) G[16] | 37 (24) G[ 8] |
| #37 | 25 (23) G[ 5] | 39 (23) G[12] |
| #38 | 39 (22) G[11] | 41 (23) G[12] |
| #39 | 42 (22) G[15] | 36 (23) G[ 7] |
| #40 | 43 (22) G[16] | 34 (23) G[ 7] |
| #41 | 44 (21) G[ 2] | 35 (23) G[ 6] |
| #42 | 46 (21) G[12] | 44 (22) G[13] |
| #43 | 48 (21) G[14] | 51 (22) G[14] |
| #44 | 45 (21) G[10] | 42 (21) G[ 8] |
| #45 | 54 (21) G[ 4] | 46 (21) G[ 9] |
| #46 | 47 (20) G[ 6] | 53 (21) G[14] |
| #47 | 37 (20) G[13] | 43 (21) G[10] |
| #48 | 51 (20) G[10] | 54 (21) G[15] |
| #49 | 38 (20) G[ 9] | 52 (21) G[14] |
| #50 | 49 (19) G[11] | 45 (21) G[10] |
| #51 | 41 (19) G[13] | 49 (20) G[12] |
| #52 | 55 (19) G[ 8] | 50 (20) G[13] |
| #53 | 53 (19) G[11] | 48 (20) G[11] |
| #54 | 52 (19) G[ 7] | 47 (20) G[11] |
| #55 | 50 (18) G[15] | 57 (20) G[15] |
| #56 | 56 (18) G[ 3] | 56 (20) G[14] |
| #57 | 58 (17) G[ 4] | 59 (19) G[15] |
| #58 | 60 (17) G[12] | 55 (18) G[12] |
| #59 | 57 (17) G[14] | 58 (18) G[13] |
| #60 | 59 (16) G[12] | 60 (18) G[16] |
| #61 | 64 (16) G[16] | 64 (17) G[16] |
| #62 | 62 (15) G[ 8] | 62 (17) G[16] |
| #63 | 61 (15) G[16] | 61 (17) G[16] |
| #64 | 63 (13) G[15] | 63 (16) G[15] |

Comment: The problem for me is that, during the first round, the top teams might already play each other. This is because we have no idea whatsoever of the strength of each team. Ideally, the last (4th) round, all top teams should be in the top group. I'll be studying your algorithm and see how I can apply it in my application. PS Who says it's not a software algorithm??

Comment: And, to complicate matters even more: what to do with 68 teams and 17 groups...

Comment: This is very specifically for 64 teams, as requested. When the number of teams doesn't fit the matrix we can use a concept called _Triangling_ but that is out of scope.

Comment: You also were very specific about the initial round being geographically based, but if you are swissing, then you want the top teams playing each other. The bigger problem is when a top team plays a bottom team in round 1. But without ranking data at the start, the first round can only be based an some arbitrary concept. Geography makes practical sense, but you can weight that allocation based on previous year results or data from qualifying matches before the tournament if you want

Comment: When you use the brute-force approach of just finding the next best team, you end up with top half of really strong teams playing weaker ones simply because they lost to really strong teams. We can address that by using round 4 as a _revenge round_ where we specifically give teams a chance to play each other again by reseeding and sorting by the seed and starting position. A better question might be _how_ to achieve these outcomes, programmatically this is not a big deal, and easy to validate, if you're running the tournament, you get to make the rules 

Comment: We organise only one tournament of this kind per year, with varying numbers of teams. All teams of a group are invited together in one sports hall close to all 4, so they can play their matches on one evening. Teams in our district can be far apart (well over 100km) we try to reduce travelling as much as possible. The finals (4th round) are in one centrally located sports hall where all teams come together. Every year, most teams usually are completely different from previous years. I'm starting a simulated tournament, generating scores and results in my application, to find the best pairing.

Comment: As I pointed out, these issues can be complex and have standard solutions, but are best explored in a new post that outlines the variable conditions. My software is used to organise national bridge tournaments, and local club events, so I get it. The matrix solution I've provided guarantees both that the winners _bubble up_ to the top groups and that no team plays another twice, without dynamically computing the group assignments

Comment: The ideal solution would be that 1) the best teams meet each other in the finals, even if they already met in earlier rounds, 2) they have interesting matches in the 2nd and 3rd rounds, and 3) venues are not too far away, but that's less important in the 3rd round.

Comment: With 64 teams, you really should do this _after_ round 4. because that gives the best even coverage of matches.  But if you want to do it instead of round 4, then you just need to rank the teams overall and apply the brute force swiss logic. Again, this detail is not clear in the original post, so going over detail here for that is out of scope